# Best way to stream videos and music from my iPhone to my TV?

Tags: iphone, appletv, streaming, cydia

So I got a samsung galaxy s advance and found out that it can stream stored music and videos wirelessly (via WIFI) to my TV. It is very efficient with no buffering time and full HD quality. 
I use an AppleTV for my iPhone, however the connection keeps dropping (the icon disappears), the buffering time takes ages to load a video stored in my iPhone, and the whole experience is very dissatisfying.

Is there another way (through an App or Cydia app) that allows streaming similar to the Galaxy S ?? I have a jailbroken iPhone so I can use cydia.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly is the Apple TV loading a video that's stored on your iPhone? Are you running a server there or are you using airplay and the phone is streaming video to the Apple TV?

Comment: Im connecting my iPhone via Airplay and streaming videos to the TV. Anyway this was asked back in 2012 and my problem is fixed now. It was a router issue that keeps dropping my connection.

Comment: Awesome update - glad it was sorted for you. I missed the accepted tick when I commented this am. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is one of those things where there's 101 ways to do it and it's just trial and error to see which works best for you. You could try wired connections using an HDMI cable  or composite AV from your iphone to your TV, or there's a variety of aftermarket apps that may work better for you. I've detailed some ideas below:

### Connect With HDMI

You'll need to purchase [an adaptor](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD098ZM/A/apple-digital-av-adapter#) for this option.

1. Plug the adapter into your device’s 30-pin iPod connector.
2. Plug one end of an HDMI cable into the HDMI port of the adapter, and
   the other end into an available HDMI port on your TV.
3. Switch your TV to the appropriate HDMI input. For earlier models
   such as the iPhone 4, the original iPad, or the fourth-generation
   iPod Touch, the display won’t be mirrored, but it will show photos
   and videos in supported apps once you start playing them on the
   device.

### Connect With Composite AV

If your TV doesn’t support HDMI, or if it doesn’t have an available connection, you can link your device to the set through an analog connection, using an [Apple Composite AV cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC748ZM/A/apple-composite-av-cable?mco=MTM3NTI1ODk).

1. Plug the adapter into your device’s 30-pin iPod connector.
2. Plug the yellow video cable at the end of the adapter into an
   available analog video port on your TV.
3. Plug the red and white audio cables at the end of the adapter into
   the red and white audio ports corresponding to the yellow video
   input on your TV.
4. Tune your TV to the appropriate composite video input. The display
   won’t be mirrored, but it will show photos and videos in supported
   apps once you start playing them on the device.

### Connect Wirelessly via Airplay

Apple developed a wireless technology called AirPlay specifically for streaming content from iOS devices to other devices that support it.

1. Make sure that your iPhone is on the same wireless network as your
   other AirPlay devices.
2. On your iPhone, double-tap the Home button.
3. Swipe the list that appears to the right, until you get to the
   volume and AirPlay settings.
4. Tap the AirPlay button to bring up a list of supported AirPlay
   devices on your network.
5. Tap the device to which you would like to stream. A TV icon next to
   the device indicates that you can stream images, video, and/or
   audio, while a speaker icon indicates that you can stream only
   audio.

### Connect Wirelessly via DLNA

If you don't want to shell out for an AirPlay-capable device, you may be able to use DLNA instead. These days, many modern TVs support streaming from a local network (wired or wireless) via the DLNA (Digital Living Network Alliance) standard. If your TV supports DLNA (or sometimes just "UPnP") streaming, you can use your iPhone as a DLNA server. Just download and install a DLNA-server app--[Media:connect](http://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/media-connect-for-dlna-upnp/id335036887?mt=8), for example--and you're good to go.

### Connect Wirelessly with Aftermarket Apps

You could try [iMediaShare](http://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/imediashare-lite-video-on-tv/id302026401?mt=8) or [AirVideoEnabler](http://www.engadget.com/2010/11/26/airvideoenabler-hack-brings-airplay-video-to-the-rest-of-your-ap/) as alternatives to the standard airplay functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am interested in Wireless streaming so the DLNA and aftermarket apps sound useful. I tried iMediaShare, however the video pauses and waits (buffers) while it plays, which is very frustrating. Is there a popular app that is known for its efficiency ?

Comment: It'll depend largely on your equipment, what you're trying to stream, what you're trying to stream to, what router you're using etc. I would give DLNA a try and see if that works better for you, I think Media:connect is free.

Answer (score -2):

I'm wondering if anyone else is using this. Here is a list of 14 useful [DLNA Streaming Apps For iPhone](http://blog.dreamcss.com/iphone/dlna-streaming-apps-for-iphone/).

Comment: Could you please summarise the blog not just give a link